# fill an array with arrays programmatically

Tags: javascript

Here is a code to create an array of arrays named `sims` through a for loop and using `str1`.

so far I need to define the `sims` length manually, equal to length of `str1` like : `let sims = [[],[],[],[]];` (four arrays equal to four words on `str1`)

how can I fill sims with arrays programmatically?

```js
var str1 = "do you ever looked";
var str2 = "do you fr ever looked";

let sims = [[],[],[],[]]; // instead I want let sims = []; 

let s1 = str1.split(" ")
let s2 = str2.split(" ")

for (var j = 0; j < s1.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
    sims[j].push(s1[j].toString());
  }
}

console.log(sims);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `initializing` the array before `pushing`

```
sims[j] = [];
```

```js
var str1 = "do you ever looked";
var str2 = "do you fr ever looked";

let sims = [];

let s1 = str1.split(" ")
let s2 = str2.split(" ")

for (var j = 0; j < s1.length; j++) {
  sims[j] = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
    sims[j].push(s1[j].toString());
  }
}

console.log(sims);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could just [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) an array to accomplish the same output, no need for any for loop at that time

```js
var str1 = "do you ever looked";
var str2 = "do you fr ever looked";

let subArrayLength = str2.split(" ").length;
let sims = str1.split(' ').map( value => new Array( subArrayLength ).fill( value ) );
console.log(sims);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a single line solution using just [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and `split`.

#### Explanation

- s1 and s2 are respectively the two strings splitted by a blankspace.
- The first array.from inherits from `s1` its length, the second argument is invoked to fill all the values. For that second argument, we care about the index (`i`).
- The second array.from inherits from `s2` its length, for that one we don't care about either of the arguments, since we will just need the `s1` element at index `i` of the previous loop (so, s2.length times s1[i]). `'' +` is just the equivalent of `toString`, which is unneeded, but the main example had it, so...

```js
var str1 = "do you ever looked", s1 = str1.split(' ');
var str2 = "do you fr ever looked", s2 = str2.split(' ');

let sims = Array.from(s1, (_,i) => Array.from(s2, () => '' + s1[i]));
console.log(sims);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could easily get this done **by pushing empty arrays** into your `sims-array` inside your first loop, like in the example below:

```js
var str1 = "do you ever looked";
var str2 = "do you fr ever looked";

let sims = [];


let s1 = str1.split(" ")
let s2 = str2.split(" ")

for (var j = 0; j < s1.length; j++) {
  sims.push([]); // this does the trick :-)
  for (var i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
    sims[j].push(s1[j].toString());
  }

}

console.log(sims);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way :

```
var s1 = str1.split(" ")
let array = []
for(var i = 0; i < s1.length; s1++) array.push(new Array())
```